# how to get golang to test a multiline output matches

Tags: string, templates, go, testing, formatting

I have the following code which generates some string output:

```
package formatter

import (
    "bytes"
    "log"
    "text/template"

    "github.com/foo/bar/internal/mapper"
)

// map of template functions that enable us to identify the final item within a
// collection being iterated over.
var fns = template.FuncMap{
    "plus1": func(x int) int {
        return x + 1
    },
}

// Dot renders our results in dot format for use with graphviz
func Dot(results []mapper.Page) string {
    dotTmpl := `digraph sitemap { {{range .}}
  "{{.URL}}"
    -> { {{$n := len .Anchors}}{{range  $i, $v := .Anchors}}
      "{{.}}"{{if eq (plus1 $i) $n}}{{else}},{{end}}{{end}}
    } {{end}}
}`

    tmpl, err := template.New("digraph").Funcs(fns).Parse(dotTmpl)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var output bytes.Buffer
    if err := tmpl.Execute(&output, results); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return output.String()
}
```

It generates output like:

```
digraph sitemap {
  "http://www.example.com/"
    -> {
      "http://www.example.com/foo",
      "http://www.example.com/bar",
      "http://www.example.com/baz"
    }
}
```

Below is a test for this functionality...

```
package formatter

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/foo/bar/internal/mapper"
)

func TestDot(t *testing.T) {
    input := []mapper.Page{
        mapper.Page{
            URL: "http://www.example.com/",
            Anchors: []string{
                "http://www.example.com/foo",
                "http://www.example.com/bar",
                "http://www.example.com/baz",
            },
            Links: []string{
                "http://www.example.com/foo.css",
                "http://www.example.com/bar.css",
                "http://www.example.com/baz.css",
            },
            Scripts: []string{
                "http://www.example.com/foo.js",
                "http://www.example.com/bar.js",
                "http://www.example.com/baz.js",
            },
        },
    }

    output := `digraph sitemap {
      "http://www.example.com/"
          -> {
              "http://www.example.com/foo",
              "http://www.example.com/bar",
              "http://www.example.com/baz"
      }
    }`

    actual := Dot(input)

    if actual != output {
        t.Errorf("expected: %s\ngot: %s", output, actual)
    }
}
```

Which fails with the following error (which is related to the outputted format spacing)...

```
--- FAIL: TestDot (0.00s)
    format_test.go:43: expected: digraph sitemap {
                  "http://www.example.com/"
                          -> {
                                  "http://www.example.com/foo",
                                  "http://www.example.com/bar",
                                  "http://www.example.com/baz"
              }
                }
        got: digraph sitemap { 
          "http://www.example.com/"
            -> { 
              "http://www.example.com/foo",
              "http://www.example.com/bar",
              "http://www.example.com/baz"
            } 
        }
```

I've tried tweaking my test `output` variable so the spacing would align with what's actually outputted from the real code. That didn't work.

I also tried using `strings.Replace()` on both my output variable and the actual outputted content and bizarrely the output from my function (even though it was passed through `strings.Replace` would *still* be multi-lined (and so the test would fail)?

Anyone have any ideas how I can make the output consistent for the sake of code verification?

Thanks.

### UPDATE

I tried the approach suggested by @icza and it still fails the test, although the output in the test *looks* more like it's expected to be:

```
=== RUN   TestDot
--- FAIL: TestDot (0.00s)
    format_test.go:65: expected: digraph sitemap {
          "http://www.example.com/"
            -> {
              "http://www.example.com/foo",
              "http://www.example.com/bar",
              "http://www.example.com/baz"
            }
        }
        got: digraph sitemap { 
          "http://www.example.com/"
            -> { 
              "http://www.example.com/foo",
              "http://www.example.com/bar",
              "http://www.example.com/baz"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore format, you can use `strings.Fields`.

```
output := strings.Fields(`digraph sitemap {
  "http://www.example.com/"
      -> {
          "http://www.example.com/foo",
          "http://www.example.com/bar",
          "http://www.example.com/baz"
  }
}`)

actual := strings.Fields(Dot(input))

if !equal(output,actual) {
    // ...
}
```

where equal is a simple function that compares two slices.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use the same indentation in the test when specifying the expected output (the same what you use in the template).

You have:

```
output := `digraph sitemap {
  "http://www.example.com/"
      -> {
          "http://www.example.com/foo",
          "http://www.example.com/bar",
          "http://www.example.com/baz"
  }
}`
```

Change it to:

```
    output := `digraph sitemap {
  "http://www.example.com/"
    -> {
      "http://www.example.com/foo",
      "http://www.example.com/bar",
      "http://www.example.com/baz"
    }
}`
```

Note that for example the final line is not indented. When you use raw string literal, every character including indentation characters is part of the literal as-is.

### Steps to create a correct, un-indented raw string literal

After all, this is completely a non-coding issue, but rather an issue of editors' auto-formatting and defining a raw string literal. An easy way to get it right is first to write an empty raw string literal, add an empty line to it and clear the auto-indentation inserted by the editor:

```
    output := `
`
```

When you have this, copy-paste the correct input before the closing backtick, e.g.:

```
    output := `
digraph sitemap {
  "http://www.example.com/"
    -> {
      "http://www.example.com/foo",
      "http://www.example.com/bar",
      "http://www.example.com/baz"
    }
}`
```

And as a last step, remove line break from the first line of the raw string literal, and you have the correct raw string literal:

```
    output := `digraph sitemap {
  "http://www.example.com/"
    -> {
      "http://www.example.com/foo",
      "http://www.example.com/bar",
      "http://www.example.com/baz"
    }
}`
```

Once you have this, running `gofmt` or auto-formatting of editors will not mess with it anymore.

**UPDATE:**

I checked your updated test result, and in the result you get, there is a space after the first line: `digraph sitemap {`, and also there's a space after the 3rd line: `-> {`, but you don't add those to your expected output. Either add those to your expected output too, or remove those spaces from the template! When comparing strings, they are compared byte-wise, every character (including white-spaces) matter.

To remove those extra spaces from the template:

```
    dotTmpl := `digraph sitemap { {{- range .}}
  "{{.URL}}"
    -> { {{- $n := len .Anchors}}{{range  $i, $v := .Anchors}}
      "{{.}}"{{if eq (plus1 $i) $n}}{{else}},{{end}}{{end}}
    } {{end}}
}`
```

Note the use of `{{-`. This is to [trim spaces around template actions](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Text_and_spaces), this was added in [Go 1.6](https://golang.org/doc/go1.6#template).

Comment: yeah this is what I tried and I still get it failing :-( it's also feels quite fiddly (as in I think I've got it matching up, but clearly I don't for it to fail) so I think I prefer the `strings.Fields` approach described by 'leaf bebop'.

Comment: When specifying the `output` variable, the first line will be indented. That's not a problem, what matters is what is between the backticks. So when you specify the expected output, subsequent lines must not be indented by your code editor. Editors are smart enough not to auto-indent content in raw string literals.

Comment: It's easy to make this wrong as if you copy-paste a valid output between backticks, code editors will format it wrong (auto-indent multi lines). The easy way to do this is to write the variable declaration, e.g. `output := \`\``, then press an Enter after the first backtick, clear the indentation and then copy-paste the valid output (and finally remove the first line break).

Comment: After all, this is completely a non-coding issue, but rather an issue of editors' auto-format and defining a raw string literal.

Comment: thanks for the updated answer. unfortunately that still fails even after following your explicit steps  I don't believe my editor is doing anything with the spaces, and the failure output in the test looks like a spot on match.

Comment: @Integralist There must be something different, e.g. tabs vs spaces. Print them as byte slices, and look for mismatched numbers. You can print the bytes like this: `fmt.Println([]byte("some string"))`.

Comment: @Integralist Hey, I checked your updated test result, and in the result you get, there is a space after the first line: `digraph sitemap { `, and also there's a space after the 3rd line: `-> { `, but you don't add those to your expected output. Either add those to your expected output too, or remove those spaces from the template!

Comment: oh interesting, so _that_ does look to be an editor issue as my editor removes spaces at the end of lines. but the template code itself needs the space because otherwise the code itself errors: i.e. this works `digraph sitemap { {{range .}}` but this doesn't `digraph sitemap {{{range .}}` that space seems to stop the compiler from breaking?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188616/discussion-between-integralist-and-icza).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that there is an extra space. in your formatted text right after `{` that seems to be your problem. You can fix it by changing your format string to this

```
`digraph sitemap {{{range .}}
  "{{.URL}}"
    -> {{{$n := len .Anchors}}{{range  $i, $v := .Anchors}}
      "{{.}}"{{if eq (plus1 $i) $n}}{{else}},{{end}}{{end}}
    }{{end}}
}`
```